# Where should Session variables be accessed and manipulated? Controller or View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

`Session` variable (among others) can be accessed and manipulated in either Controller or View. To respect the best practice, where should the `Session` variable be accessed and manipulated, Controller or View?

Answer (score 3):

In the `Controller` - A `View`, as its name suggests, should only View data - whereas a `Controller` would *control* it.